# Where can I find what drivers built in my yocto project Linux kernel image?

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, yocto

I'm using **Yocto** project to build a **linux kernel image** following these steps:
 https://www.at91.com/linux4sam/bin/view/Linux4SAM/Sama5d27Som1EKMainPage

For some reasons I just want to reduce my Image size so I can flash it on QSPI 8 Mega octet memory. I have tried to reduce the size of my rootFS, I have removed some **packages** that I found in **.manifest file**  and some Distro features. But I did not find how can I modify the kernel size which size is fixed ( 4.2 Mega octet ).

I think that when I can remove some drivers that I don't need the kernel size will be reduced. 
I just want to know how can I find what **drivers** are built in my image and where can I find them ? and later how can I delete the ones that I don't need ?
Thank you.

Comment: check defconfig and lsmod?

Comment: Yocto defconfig files for you board should be found in subfolders [here](https://github.com/linux4sam/meta-atmel/tree/sumo/recipes-kernel/linux).

Comment: I followed this path: meta-atmel/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-at91-4.14/sama5 and I found defconfig file with list of configs which are set to y or m

Answer (score 0):

if you check the .config file that was generated for your BSP, it will show what drivers (and other things) were built into your kernel (check for the 'y' on all the options).

Such file should be somewhere in:
tmp/work//linux-yocto//linux-*-build/.config

Sorry that I can't give you the exact location, but it literally depends on what BSP/MACHINE you are building for.

Also, if you want to modify such configuration, you can call:

```
$ bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel
```

that will bring up the menuconfig ncurses interface, in which you can not only see what is installed but also modify what you need.

Comment: I can not find .config file following your path. I just found all-poky-linux  cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi , sama5d27_som1_ek_sd-poky-linux-gnueabi , x86_64-linux , x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux  directories

Comment: I have opened the kernel menuconfig and i have removed options that i don't need and i bitbaked again the system but this don't change the size of the kernel